# How do you check if a form field has data in twig template that is rendering a controller

Tags: symfony, twig

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231238/want-to-access-form-fields-in-twig-using-symfony) . What I want to know is how to check if the entity variable exist/is defined/not null. I thought I could do this:

```
{% if entity.orgId is defined %}
{{ render(controller(
    'CompanyNameofBundle:OrgMember:test', {'orgid':entity.orgId})) }}
{% endif %}
```

But if entity.orgId is null I get an exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The product does not exist").

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for null in Twig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264889/how-to-check-for-null-in-twig)

Comment: Who's throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller to return null instead of exception:

```
public function testAction($orgid = null) {
    if (!$orgid) { return null; }
// Rest of code.
}
```

Comment: That was the ellegant approach I was looking for! @malcolm

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Don't call the render controller using the check

   ```
   {% if entity.orgId is defined and entity.orgId is not null %}
   ```
2. Make the testAction in the OrgMemberController null-safe (check if the parameter orgid is null)

Comment: 1) Doesn't work still gets the same An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The product does not exist") .
2) I can't do that because I still need the object. The render controller requires that parameter though to function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% if entity.orgId is defined %}
    {% if entity.orgId is null %}
        {# do something #}
    {% else %}
        {# do anythingelse #}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as the one above except you have broken it into two for loops.

Comment: There is a litle difference, i used  `is null` instead `is not null`

Comment: That is pretty in material in any case the is issue had to be checked in the controller because since it was never set to null it wasn't returning anything other than an error.